# Why is $\int_0^x \int_0^u f(t)(u-t)dt \,du = \int_0^x\int_0^uf(t)(x-u)dt\,du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654996/prove-int-0x-fracfux-unndu-int-0x-int-0u-n-dotsb-int) I learned that $$\int_0^x \int_0^u f(t)(u-t)dt \,du = \int_0^x\int_0^uf(t)(x-u)dt\,du.$$

I've been trying to come up with an intuitive reason why this should be so, like a geometric argument for example. Can someone think of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is arbitrary, it should be eliminated from the identity; it does not contribute anything to its meaning. To this end, it helps to change the order of integration, because then $f$ can be taken out of the inner integral. The identity becomes
$$\int_0^x f(t)  \int_t^x (u-t)\,du  \,dt  = \int_0^x f(t) \int_t^x (x-u)\,du\, dt$$
(Concerning the limits: note that the integration takes place over $0\le t\le u\le x$).

Again, $f$ is arbitrary: the only way for these integrals to be equal is if the inner integrals are equal: $$\int_t^x (u-t)\,du = \int_t^x (x-u)\,du$$
Which indeed has a geometric interpretation: two triangles with the same base and height have the same area. On the plot below, $[t,x]=[2,5]$.

[image: triangles]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and just what I was looking for! Thank you.